# Какие представления Model из MVC выбирают для разработки под Android?

Tags: java, android, mvc, controller

Изучая разнообразные ресурсы по разработке на платформу андроид столкнулся с использованием архитектуры MVC. Как я правльно понял это Model.View.Controller где Model - это, грубо говоря, та часть программы (в виде кода или чего либо еще) реализующая хранение данных в приложении. 
Собственно сам вопрос - какой способ выбрать? Учитывая то, что разработка под платформу android, по большей части ведется с помощью средств языка java вспоминается несколько способов - такие как properties, preferences, какой либо шифрованный тип данных, наподобие p12, базы данных - SQLite. 
Так какой же способ оптимальней и что должно повлиять на выбор того или иного способа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, моделью в паттерне MVC могут быть не только всевозможные типы данных, но и "голая" бизнес-логика. Модель здесь это то, что должно быть отображено на экране, View - как отображено и контроллер - как взаимодействует "с миром"

Насчет же самих данных, то многое зависит от непосредственно данных: их вида, способа получения, места изначального хранения, решаемых задач и индивидуальных предпочтений разработчика (опыта и образования) и здесь не может быть однозначно-верного ответа. Для решения одной задачи будет уместен один вариант, а для другой этот же вариант совсем не приемлем.

Основные же источники данных в Android это в первую очередь БД SQLite и следующее - файлы с какой то структурой - JSON, XML и тп.
Преференсы вовсе не предназначены для хранения именно данных - их применение сохранение состояния настоек и прочие такие "флаги".

Для себя я выбрал ORM [Realm](http://realm.io) по следующим причинам:

1. Представление и хранение данных в виде классической POJO-модели
2. Не SQLLite надстройка. Собственный движок, написанный на С++
3. Скорость
4. Развитый API, который постоянно дополняется и внятный синтаксис.

   1. Модель может содержать произвольные методы с логикой, а не только геттеры\сеттеры полей
   2. Получив по запросу выборку из БД и внося в нее изменения, эти изменения заносятся сразу в БД. Не требуется отдельная логика для сохранения изменений
5. Широкий круг применений, так как может использоваться не только как БД (фильтры, выборки, связывания и тп.), но и как просто хранилище неструктурированной информации.

Недостатки:

1. Бета-версия, соответственно некоторых инструментов, привычных при работе СУБД вообще и SQLite в частности, еще не реализовано.