# ORM или SQLite в Android

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

На данный момент, в процессе изучения Android SDK и Java.
Предполагал, что для локального хранения данных используется только SQLite и Shared Preferences.
Недавно наткнулся на [статью с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/245299/), которая добавила некую неопределённость:

Во многих крупных проектах используют ORM, которые значительно уменьшают количество  шаблонного kода, при незначительной потери производительности. (например [GreenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/))

Стоит ли на начальных этапах писать приложения с локальным хранением данных, используя ORM? Или лучше использовать стандартный класс SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: ещё есть realm:
https://realm.io/

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+WoraweeSattayavinij/posts/jCzzCeNLRyP

Comment: Сравнение различных ORM - https://habrahabr.ru/post/281226/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безусловно, использовать ORM рекомендуется во всех случаях, кроме явного преимущества за SQLite по каким то критическим причинам:имеются уже готовые базы большого объема, очень специфические запросы, которые можно оформить только на полноценном языке SQL, критична скорость выборки данных и тому подобное.

ORM очень сильно упрощает как работу с данными, так и использовать их во много легче, чем обертку для SQLLite в Android, так же позволяет использовать POJO-модели, вместо выборок и множество других преимуществ. Из недостатков: основной - скорость работы.

Из всего многообразия ORM рекомендовал бы в первую очередь обратить внимание на [*Realm*](http://realm.io) , по причинам, изложенным в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511147/177345)