# Сохранение данных ArrayList при уничтожении activity

Tags: java, android

У нас есть активность а адаптером, в которой есть массив(например, мы добавили 1 элемент), при переходе в другую активность и возврате обратно у нас пересоздается адаптер(и его ArrayList), => значения массива теряются. В этом массиве всегда будет 1 элемент.

Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на новую активность и возврате обратно данные массива сохранялись.

Comment: static константа заполняет адаптер и только потом показывает ее

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нужно хранить динамические данные во внешнем хранилище не зависящем от жизненного цикла и времени жизни активити (БД, файл, JSON, XML и тд.), а не локальных переменных. Работают с этими данными также напрямую (например, с выборкой в Cursor из SQLite), делая выборки из источника данных и извлекая их в адаптере,  а не перегоняют в разные массивы и прочие бессмысленные прослойки.

Всякие массивы и коллекции в основном только для учебных примеров в силу упрощения этого примера и иногда для статических данных (которые не будут изменяться во время работы программы).
Никакие настоящие программы не используют выбранный вами способ хранения, в силу его крайней ущербности и костыльного сопровождения, к тому же, при закрытии программы ваши данные все равно будут потеряны.

**UPD**
Так же часто в примерах можно встретить использование классов-моделей (POJO-моделей), вместо "сырых" данных, таких как `Cursor`, парсинг JSON или XML, заполняются такие классы-модели прямо в коде и складываются затем в какой-нибудь `ArrayList`.  Класс-модель действительно намного удобнее в работе против "сырых" данных, но демонстрируемая техника также является учебной и упрощенной для лучшего понимания. В действительности такие классы-модели заполняются либо через различные классы-врапперы, которые являются буфером между "сырыми" данными и запрашивающим эти данные кодом. Враппер "на лету" преобразует запросы к данным и обрабатывает полученный результат, предоставляя его в более удобном виде. Есть как [совсем простые решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535778/177345), для несложных запросов, так и ORM "монстры", вроде библиотек ORMLite, GreenDao.
Другой стороной выступают "чистые" noSQL базы, [вроде Realm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511147/177345), которые работают напрямую с классами-моделями - это самый предпочтительный способ в 99% случаев работы с данными.

Часто можно встретить такое неправильное решение, как выборка всех данных из БД и сохранение их в какой-то `ArrayList`, где они потом обрабатываются - сортируются, фильтруются и тп.. Это грубый и очень низкопроизводительный антипаттерн. Любая БД имеет на порядки более мощные и быстрые инструменты обработки собственных данных. Как язык SQL (для работы с SQLite), так и методы, реализуемые любой ORM - весьма совершенны и позволяют сделать практически любую и немыслимую выборку, при условии правильной организации самой БД.
Получать в работу нужно только требующиеся в данный момент и заранее подготовленные средствами самой БД, данные, через правильные запросы, а не возиться с очень медленным `ArrayList` и его примитивными возможностями по обработке.

Вообще это довольно сложная и очень объемная тема, здесь немного освещены только самые верхушки по работе с данными в приложении. Главное, что нужно усвоить - учиться программировать надо по книгам и учебникам, где дается систематизированный и последовательный подход, а не по разрозненным урокам на сайтах, которые набросаны наспех, лишь бы работало, максимально упрощены и никак не учитывают важнейшие и краеугольные части разработки, такие как архитектура приложения и грамотное взаимодействие его частей.