# Разделить данные по блокам в Gridview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем доброго времени суток.
Вывожу все данные с таблицы БД в Gridview. Все они идут сплошным списком. **Как** отделить каждую запись с базы от другой. **Разделить** данные в Gridview по блоках.
В данный момент вод так - 
[image: Есть так]

Надо - [image: Надо]

Так вывожу данные в GridViev.

> Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM logpsw", null);
>
> ```
>     final int record = cursor.getCount();            // Количество записей в таблице базы данных
>
>     cursor.moveToFirst();
>
>
>     test = new ArrayList<>();
>     if (record == 0) {
>         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ReadRecorsDB.this, "Засипи в базе >отсутствуют, добавьте новую запись", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>         toast.show();
>     } else
>
>     {
>         while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
>             test.add(cursor.getString(i));
>
>             //datedb += cursor.getString(i) + " | ";
>             i++;
>
>             if (i == columnCount) {              
>
>                 cursor.moveToNext();
>                 i = 0; //                    //test.clear();
>                 }
>
>         }
>
>         cursor.close();
>                     adapter = new TripleArrayAdapter(this, joined, test);  > //переделанный адаптер под себя для вывода двух столбцов в GridViev
>
>             readgrid.setAdapter(adapter);
>                     }
> ```

Comment: рекомендую прочитать, почему [копировать содержимое выборки из БД в коллекцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) это очень плохое решение. По вопросу: просто в разметке одной ячейки "нарисуйте" линию снизу (например View с фоном цвета линии высотой в 1dp)

Comment: Вставлял линию в разметку. <View
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="@color/some_color" />. Получалась после каждой строчки а надо после блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Руслан, не напишу для Вас код, а вот на верный путь наставлю Вас. В даном случае будет лучше использовать RecyclerView. 
Для начала вы должны создать клас (например RegistrationNotepad), описывающий ваш объект с полями

```
id;
date;
siteName;
siteUrl;
login;
...
description;
```

затем описать layout для одного обьекта там уже в низу и лини можете добавить или вообще что захотите.(Как я понял из примера - количество строк статическое). Затем создать ViewHolder для данного обьекта .
После чего создаете список из обектов RegistrationNotepad

```
List<RegistrationNotepad> registrationNotepad = new ArrayList<>();
```

И заполнаете его из базы пообьектно. (думаю в базе у вас примерно такая же таблица должна быть). 
Затем создаете адаптер и передаете ему это список и в OnBindViewHolder описываете логику заполнения полей из обьекта. В интернете полно информации как рабоать с RecyclerView. Дерзайте :-)

Comment: Спасибо Vlad Pylyp буду разбираться с RecyclerView.

Comment: Все получилось супер. Большое спасибо.

Comment: @ruslan Рад был помочь ) Если вам нравиться решение, отметьте его как правильное )