# Не выводит первую строку в list view

Tags: java, android

Имеется такой вот код, он выводит информацию из SQLite в лист. И все работает, нооо.. самая первая запись не выводится, оно ее просто пропускает и начинает со второй

```
  final SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("Messeg",null,null,null,null,null,null);
      if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
         // while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

              UpList.add(0, new DialogSaveData(
                     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fr")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fr")),
                     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"))
             ));

   CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(MainActivity.this, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
              //присваиваем адаптер списку
              listChat.setAdapter(adapter);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


          }
       }else {
          dataMess.setText("no table");
       }



   }
```

Путем тыка подозрение пало на строку  `while (cursor.moveToNext()){`
т.к если убрать этот цикл то в лист выведется только первая запись.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить while на do while.

Comment: рекомендую прочитать, почему [копировать содержимое выборки из БД в коллекцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) это очень плохое решение. ничего, кроме потерь времени и ресурсов устройства эта техника не дает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально `Cursor` стоит на позиции ДО первой записи.

В строке

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
```

вы его передвигаете на первую запись, и следующий сразу за ним

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
```

передвигает его на вторую запись.

В Вашем случае строка

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
```

не нужна, а для обработки проблемы с пустым результирующим набором сделайте проверку на количество элементов в `UpList` после цикла

Answer (score 2):

Присваивайте первый элемент до входа в цикл while().

1) cursor.moveToFirst();
2) присвоить первый элемент в list
3) цикл cursor.moveToNext() по остальным элементам курсора.

Answer (score 0):

А такой вариант

> final int record = cursor.getCount(); // Количество записей в таблице
> базы данных
>
> final int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount(); // Количество полей в
> таблице
>
> ```
>     cursor.moveToFirst();
>     test = new ArrayList<>();
>     if (record == 0) {
>         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ReadRecorsDB.this, "Записи в базе   отсутствую, добавьте новую запись", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>         toast.show();
>     } else> 
>     {
>         while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
>             test.add(cursor.getString(i));
>             i++;
>             if (i == columnCount) {
>                 cursor.moveToNext();
>                 i = 0;                       
>                 }   
>     cursor.close();
> ```