# Динамический поиск по списку

Tags: android, listview, list, arraylist

Доброго времени суток! Не могу сделать нормальный поиск по списку, а именно при вводе данных он показывает то, что надо, но если убрать текст из EditText'а, то список обратно не восстанавливается. Помогите решить эту проблему, пожалуйста.

Код, который привязан к EditText'у

```
var search = view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.search) as EditText
    search.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int, after:Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int) {
            var k: Int = 0
            var size: Int = recovery.size
            while(k < size){
                var obj: String = recovery.get(k).colorName
                if(!obj.contains(s.toString())){
                    if(s.toString() == ""){
                        initList(view!!.context, 0)
                    }else {
                        recovery.removeAt(k)
                    }
                }
                size = recovery.size
                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                k++
                recovery = listOfDMC
            }
        }
        override fun afterTextChanged(s:Editable) {
        }
    })
```

Тут создается копия листа(recovery), и в ней должен происходить поиск и удаление не нужных элементов. Я не ищу в listOFDMC т.к. он достаточно длинный и инициализировать его заново занимает некоторое время.

Код метода initList

```
fun initList(context: Context, type: Int){
    var db = DBHelper(context)
    var sql = db.writableDatabase
    var req = "SELECT * FROM ${CreateTable.dbName}"
    var cursor = sql.rawQuery(req, null)
    cursor.moveToFirst()

    var k: Int = 0;
    var size: Int = cursor.count

    while(k < size){
        var preview: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CreateTable.COLOR_NUMBER))

        when(type){
            0 -> {
                var colorDMC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CreateTable.DMC_COLOR))
                var haveDMC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CreateTable.DMC_HAVE))
                var notHaveDMC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CreateTable.DMC_NOT_HAVE))
                recovery.add(MaterialDeafult(preview, colorDMC, haveDMC, notHaveDMC))
            }
        //...
        //
        //...
        }

        cursor.moveToNext()
        k++
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Вот [ответ в котором рабочее решение поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) по базе данных/ Могу сразу сказать, что извлечение данных из БД в коллекцию [бесполезная и даже вредная операция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), которая не дает ничего, кроме усложнения и ухудшения кода - рекомендую вам избавится от этого груза и работать напрямую с курсором.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать так