# Android IndexOutOfBoundExeption Invalid array range

Tags: android, массивы, sqlite

Есть у меня функция, вот её код:

```
public void show_table_bd() {
    f_LoadingBar();
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // делаем запрос всех данных из таблицы TRANSACTIONS, получаем Cursor
    Cursor c = db.query("TRANSACTIONS", null, kakoePole, whatVibrat, null, null, "CURRENTDATA ASC");

    Allmoney = new BigDecimal("0").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    AllmoneyRashod = new BigDecimal("0").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    AllmoneyDohod = new BigDecimal("0").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    int size = 0;
    height_gridview(size);
    //Расходы
    for (int i = 0; i < AllRashod.length; i++) {
        AllRashod[i] = new BigDecimal("0").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }

    // ставим позицию курсора на первую строку выборки
    // если в выборке нет строк, вернется false

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ID");
        int idDohRash = c.getColumnIndex("IDDOHRASH");
        int CurrentDataColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("CURRENTDATA");
        int accountColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ACCOUNT");
        int rashodColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("RASHOD");
        int moneyColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("MONEY");
        int iconSchetColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("IDSCHET");
        int iconKatColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("IDKAT");

        idDohRashbd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        idstr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        schet = new ArrayList<String>();
        oper = new ArrayList<String>();
        sum = new ArrayList<Double>();
        idSchet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        idKat = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        currentdata = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        do {
            // получаем значения по номерам столбцов
            idDohRashbd.add(0, c.getInt(idDohRash));
            idstr.add(0, c.getInt(idColIndex));
            currentdata.add(0, c.getInt(CurrentDataColIndex));
            schet.add(0, c.getString(accountColIndex));
            oper.add(0, c.getString(rashodColIndex));
            sum.add(0, c.getDouble(moneyColIndex));
            idSchet.add(0, c.getInt(iconSchetColIndex));
            idKat.add(0, c.getInt(iconKatColIndex));

            Allmoney = Allmoney.add(convertMoney(c.getInt(iconKatColIndex), c.getDouble(moneyColIndex)));

            if (c.getInt(idDohRash) == 0) {
                AllmoneyRashod = AllmoneyRashod.add(convertMoney(c.getInt(iconKatColIndex), c.getDouble(moneyColIndex)));
            }

            if (c.getInt(idDohRash) == 1) {
                AllmoneyDohod = AllmoneyDohod.add(convertMoney(c.getInt(iconKatColIndex), c.getDouble(moneyColIndex)));
            }

            if (0 < idKat.get(0) && idKat.get(0) < 11) {
                AllRashod[idKat.get(0) - 1] = AllRashod[idKat.get(0) - 1].add(convertMoney(c.getInt(iconKatColIndex), c.getDouble(moneyColIndex)));
            }

            size++;
            // переход на следующую строку
            // а если следующей нет (текущая - последняя), то false - выходим из цикла
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        del_window = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.del_window);
        kategory_grid.setVisibility(GONE);
        gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(this, getBaseContext(), idDohRashbd, idstr, currentdata, idSchet, schet, idKat, oper, sum, size, komment_window, komment_txt, del_window));
        height_gridview(size);

        size = 0;
        switch1.setChecked(true);
    }

    diagrammProgress();
    f_LoadingBar();
    if (!flag_from_kat) {
        switch1.performClick();
        switch1.performClick();
    }
    c.close();
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

Да большая, но дело не в этом, в общем на первой строке "if (c.moveToFirst()) {" я получаю исключение java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundExeption: Invalid array range: 10 to 10. Я первый раз получаю такое исключении и вообще хз, что делать прошу помощи.

Comment: Вы что-то путаете - `Cursor.moveToFirst()` не вызывает исключений. Наверное Вы изменили код, но не обновили приложение на устройстве. Более вероятно, что ошибка в строке `AllRashod[idKat.get(0) - 1] = AllRashod[idKat.get(0) - 1].add(convertMoney(c.getInt(iconKatColIndex), c.getDouble(moneyColIndex)));`

Comment: @woesss ну вообще до строки которую вы указали дело вообще не доходит, я смогу отловить эту ошибку только когда по наставил красных точек ну на которых приложение останавливается и показывает все имеющиеся переменные, и как раз ошибка указывает именно на Cursor.moveToFirst(), но мне интересна не то где находится ошибка, а то что она говорит?? я переискал весь интернет, но так и не нашел что значит эта ошбика

Comment: Если Вы изменили код, а дебаггер работает по старому коду - он может не верно указывать строку. Ошибка означает, что происходит обращение к массиву по индексу выходящему за пределы диапазона.

Comment: @woesss только что внимательно все проверил и выяснил, что java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundExeption: Invalid array range: 10 to 10 присваивается массиву AllRashod[i] и после вот этой функции 
for (int i = 0; i < AllRashod.length; i++) {
        AllRashod[i] = new BigDecimal("0").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    } и про пределы массива я тоже слышал, но как может быть выход за пределы если массив изначально был определен как
BigDecimal[] AllRashod = new BigDecimal[10];

Comment: В цикле не должно быть - он в каждой итерации сверяется с длиной массива. Может глюк какой - попробуйте сделать ребилд проекта и дебаг по новой.

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что вы обучались программированию в индусской школе. Во многом благодаря таким творениям за Android закрепилась репутация тормозной и глючной системы. Сперва вам нужно понять [следующую информацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345). То, что делаете вы - ничем не оправданный расход ресурсов. В перспективе вам нужно читать литературу по разработке, как Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2017 - это научит вас правильной архитектуре и принятым практикам в разработке.

Comment: Код, что у вас в вопросе - это никуда не годится, не стоит самому выдумывать какие то невероятные костыли для решения типовых задач. Все уже давно придумано и "вылизано" до совершенства. Понятно, что опыта не хватает, но это не повод писать такое - это повод узнать, как делают правильно. На вашем этапе не надо гуглить по мелким проблемам, нужно читать систематизированную литературу (книги по разработке), чтобы было целостное представление.

Answer (score 0):

Все я нашел решение данной задачи я просто заместо итерации:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllRashod.length; i++) {
    AllRashod[i] = new BigDecimal("0").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

Написал вот что:

```
Arrays.fill(AllRashod, BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

После чего ошибка пропала.

Comment: но Вы поняли *почему* она пропала?

Comment: цикл у вас идет с 0 индекса по 10. 0 индекс = 1 элемент. 10 индекс = 11 элемент. Вам нужно было поставить `AllRashod.length - 1`