# Извлечь из базы данных

Tags: android, база-данных, курсор

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь внести данные (2 текстовых поля) в бд и извлечь их в другое активити. Подскажите, по какой логике мне двигаться дальше? Нужно извлечь отдельным методом и передавать в списки или как-то иначе? 
PS:В логах вывелась информация что бд создана и данные извлечены.

Код базы

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "notes";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int DB_KEY = 0;
    public static final String DB_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String DB_NOTE = "note";



    public DataBase(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + DB_NAME + "("
                + " _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + DB_TITLE + " text,"
                + DB_NOTE + " text)");

    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DB_NAME );
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

}

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBase.DB_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int tIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.DB_TITLE);
                int nIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.DB_NOTE);
                do {
                    String getTitle = ("title" + cursor.getString(tIndex));
                    String getNote = ("note" + cursor.getString(nIndex));

                    Note noteFromDB = new Note();
                    noteFromDB.setTitleText(getTitle);
                    noteFromDB.setNoteText(getNote);

                arrayList.add(noteFromDB);


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
```

Comment: обычно делается DAO-класс, который реализует операции чтения из БД, вставки, удаления и проч. (в вашем случае все это может реализовть ваш класс Database), затем обращаются к экземпляру этого класса, когда,например, требуется получить данные (к примеру `database.getAll()` - получить все данные). По поводу "передавать в списки" - как правило, это [плохая идея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), которая ничего, кроме потери ресурсов и производительности не несет (эффективнее, хотя и менее удобно работать напрямую с курсором). Вы можете рассмотреть новый инструмент google - Room

Comment: в книге "Д. Гриффитс, Д. Гриффитс - Head First. Программирование для Android - 2016" на странице 469 начинает тема по работе с БД, там очень понятно все описано, попробуйте изучить

Comment: Спасибо. Приму к сведению