# Почему ругается на отсутствие данных?

Tags: android, recyclerview, arraylist, recyclerview.adapter

[image: Есть такой активити у приложения.]

Для него использую RecycleView. Данные хранятся в базе данных. Удаляю данные из активити движением пальца влево. Но вот одно но, выдает ошибку, что не найден такой индекс, не могу понять, почему такое выдает.

Код получения всех данных на экран:

```
/*Получение всех данных из SQLite*/
public List<Notes> getAllNotes(){
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<Notes> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC";
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select, null);

    Log.e("LOG", "LIST:");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            notes = new Notes();

            notes.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            notes.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            notes.setText(cursor.getString(2));

            Log.e("LOG", "id = " + notes.getId() + "; title = " + notes.getTitle() +
            "; text = " + notes.getText() + "\n");

            list.add(notes);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Также логирую, чтобы убедиться, какие данные записываются, на данный момент два объекта, и вот такие у них данные:

```
E/LOG: LIST:
E/LOG: id = 6; title = 6; text = 6
E/LOG: id = 5; title = 5; text = 5
```

Метод для удаления данных:

```
public void removeItem(int position){
    Log.e("LOG", "REMOVE:");
    Log.e("LOG", "id = " + notesList.get(position).getId() +
            "; title = " + notesList.get(position).getTitle() +
            "; text = " + notesList.get(position).getText() + "\n");

    notesList.remove(position);

    notesHandler.deleteNotes(new Notes(notesList.get(position).getId()));

    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

Также логирую, данные сходятся, когда выбираю элемент. То есть если хочу удалить, первый элемент, то выдает:

```
id = 6; title = 6; text = 6
```

И удаляет он только из List, а из базы данных удаляет следующий элемент, то есть:

```
id = 5; title = 5; text = 5
```

Можно узнать, если перезагрузить активити, то список совсем другой:

```
LIST:
id = 6; title = 6; text = 6
```

Удалил совсем не тот. И сам метод, который должен получать позицию удаляемого элемента, узнать его данные и удалить из базы данных.

```
/*Удаление данных*/
public void deleteNotes(Notes notes){
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME,
            KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(notes.getId())});
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Удаляет по id.
Странно, не могу понять что не так, вроде получает все данные, правильно, а удаляет совсем не тот элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cначала нужно удалять из базы, а потом из списка. Вы же получаете ID из списка в адаптере, а позицию эту удалили - на этой позиции в списке теперь следующий элемент.

```
public void removeItem(int position){

    notesHandler.deleteNotes(new Notes(notesList.get(position).getId()));
    notesList.remove(position);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

PS: в метод `deleteNotes()` логичнее передавать ID в виде числа, а не объект из которого этот ID извлекается, тем более создавая для этого новый объект, пожалейте устройство и сборщик мусора ..

PPS: так же рекомендую ознакомиться с [этой информацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) и как то оптимизировать адаптер.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.