# configChanges="orientation|screenSize" против сохранения данных в Bundle

Tags: android, rotation

Всем привет. Имеется приложение сложного типа, в котором есть 3 фрагмента на одной активности. В каждом фрагменте при запуске загружаются данные из базы данных.

Поначалу я не беспокоился о поворотах экрана и делал все по общему принципу: Например для показа диалогов я создавал методы, в них передавал данные (к примеру, текст в `EditText`), при повороте сохранял все данные в `Bundle` (показан ли диалог, введенный текст) а в `onCreate` фрагмента если `savedInstanceState != null` то я брал данные из Bundle и показывал диалог.

Данные из адаптера списка я тоже сохранял в `Bundle`с помощью GSON. Позже я получил баг: если данных было слишком много, то `Bundle` падал из-за нехватки памяти. С горем пополам сделал сохранение данных из адаптера в статичную переменную. Но все равно приложение работало не стабильно.

В конце концов сейчас я убрал все это убрал и выставил в манифесте на активность `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`. Вылезли баги из всех библиотек, пришлось в них редактировать код, в итоге получилось. Но с диалогами я засел. Не пойму, как им обновлять размеры, например если открыть окно в горизонтальной ориентации (контент не умещается, он сжат в `ScrollView`) и при повороте на вертикальную ориентацию эта самая "сжатость" остается.

Как правильно обработать повороты? Дальше искать решение с диалогами или вернуть все как было? А как тогда сохранять данные адаптера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно запрещать пересоздание активити при повороте, все это только выйдет боком (что вы будете делать, когда, например, патченые вами библиотеки обновятся, опять править?). К тому же сохранять состояние все равно придется, даже если и запретить поворот, так как приложение помимо этого может быть, скажем, отправлено пользователем в фон (например, глянуть какое пришло сообщение в мессенджер и вернуться к вашей программе) - никому не понравится, если после такого простого и обычного действия все данные будут потеряны.

Другое дело, что хранить состояния списков в переменных (так же и динамических списках) - [детский сад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), уже давно придуманы эффективные способы хранить данные большого объема без проблем с жизненным циклом (БД всевозможных форматов, файл и тп.), при восстановлении они читаются непосредственно оттуда. В Bundle сохраняется только текущее состояние (позиция, какая то конфигурация: настройки фильтров, сортировка и тп.), а не сами пользовательские данные.

На сегодняшний день гугл активно продвигает новую фичу - [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html). Данная архитектура полностью покрывает всю структуру - от источника данных до их представления на экране. Включает много решений, выглядящих разумно, и что особенно ценно в контексте вашего вопроса - заботится о восстановлении состояния представления при поворотах, уходах в фон, асинхронных операциях и тп. без костылей с JSON-ами в Bundle или того лучше - статических переменных. При этом источником данных не обязательно должен быть Room, если это критично, но любая БД, сетевой запрос и прочие хранилища данных.

Comment: Но как быть, если данных в Bundle слишком много, и весь код страдает из-за всего этого? При повороте не надо грузить из бд, так сказали

Comment: их не должно быть слишком много ни в одном разумном сценарии. Кто сказал не грузить из БД, что тогда взамен сказали делать, в Bundle данные писать? - я бы не стал слушать таких специалистов. Добавил компромиссное решение в ответ, против него никто сказать ничего не сможет :)

Comment: спасибо большое, надо разобраться