# Заполнение массива данными из форм Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

Есть активность с 3 полями и кнопкой Submit. Этот метод возвращает готовый объект, который нужно занести в массив.

```
public class AddColdArmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<Weapon> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_cold_arm);

 public Weapon createWeapon(){

    EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cold_arm_name);
    Editable nameEditTable = editName.getText();
    String name = nameEditTable.toString();

    EditText editCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cold_arm_cost);
    int cost = Integer.parseInt(editCost.getText().toString());

    EditText editLength = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cold_arm_length);
    int length = Integer.parseInt(editLength.getText().toString());

    return new ColdArm(name, cost, length);
}
 public void Submit(View view) {
     list.add(createWeapon());
   }
}
```

При нажатии на Submit объект добавляется в коллекцию

Но сам list существует только в одной активности. Стоит выйти назад и снова открыть форму - данные теряются и все начинает записываться в чистый list.

Пробовал создавать отдельный класс для добавление в List

```
public class Creator {
List<Weapon> list = new ArrayList<>();
AddColdArmActivity coldArmActivity = new AddColdArmActivity();

public void addCold(){
    list.add(coldArmActivity.createWeapon());
}
```

И вызывать его потом таким образом:

```
   public void Submit(View view) {
        creator.addCold();
}
```

Но приложение просто зацикливается выдавай примерно следующее:

> I/hwaps: JNI_OnLoad
>
> I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
>
> I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed  86041(3MB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 30MB/32MB,  paused
>   5.729ms total 48.130ms
>
> I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark  sweep GC freed 3094(146KB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0%  free, 32MB/32MB, paused
>   6.173ms total 21.352ms

Идеи у меня уже закончились. Может быть кто-то сможет подсказать?

Comment: вам нужно хранилище, не зависящее от жизненного цикла - БД, файл JSON или XML и тому подобное. Туда вы будете записывать свои значения, а потом читать при необходимости. О [работе с данными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) в Anfroid

Comment: Можно пожалуйста подробней про xml, или может ссылочку?

Comment: XML и JSON используется в основном для сетевых решений. Для локальных приложений лучший выбор - БД, которых сейчас большой выбор: чистый SQLite, Room, Realm, Objectbox и др. Ссылку смотрите в моем комментарии выше на вопрос с аналогичной проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте SharedPreferences — постоянное хранилище на платформе Android, используемое приложениями для хранения своих настроек, например. Это хранилище является относительно постоянным, пользователь может зайти в настройки приложения и очистить данные приложения, тем самым очистив все данные в хранилище.

Как мне кажется это лучшее решение вашей проблемы. Повесть о нем можно в интернете , статей достаточно много.