# Как сохранить список добавленных объектов в listview androidstudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Как сохранить список добавленных **объектов в listview** в самом приложении?
Для строковых значений я ранее использовала saveArrayList() и loadArrayList() через SharedPreferences

Мое приложение сейчас, принимаю в корзину объект:

```
//Создаю адаптер
    cartAdapter = new AdapterCart(this, products);
//Передаю объект
    Product obj = (Product) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Product");
    products.add(obj);
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvcart);
    lvMain.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
```

saveArrayList:

```
private void saveArrayList(String name, ArrayList<Product> list) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Product s : list) sb.append(s).append("<s>");
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 3, sb.length());
        editor.putString(name, sb.toString()).apply();
    }
```

loadArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<Product> loadArrayList(String name) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Product[] products = prefs.getProduct(name).split("<s>");
        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(products));
        return list;
    }
```

Как тут реализовать save и load? Принимаю любую информацию! Заранее спасибо Вам, дорогие!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простого сохранения и восстановления списка `ArrayList` вы можете использовать простую [библиотеку Paper](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper), которая как раз позволяет это сделать без затей. То есть вам надо перед закрытием приложения сохранять с ее помощью свои динамические списки, а при открытии восстанавливать. Библиотека позволяет сохранять списки объектов любого типа, то есть у содержимого, как например для `SharedPreferencesё` или `Bundle` ограничение на простые типы, здесь нет

Однако, если вы делаете что то вроде магазина или менеджера учета финансов, то вам однозначно нужно осваивать работу с БД. Магазин на динамических списках - это совершенно не серьезно. Сейчас есть два основных тренда: NoSQL БД [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest) и ORM [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).

Выбор за вами, хотя именно для магазина однозначно более уместна реляционная база данных (то есть ORM Room), так как вся структура имеет табличную природу.
 Кроме того, решение отлично интегрируется с остальными инструментами [*Architecture Components*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html), как `LiveData`, `ViewModel` и [`support.v7.ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html) (новый адаптер для `RecyclerView`, доступный с библиотеки поддержки 27.1.0 и решающий вопросы автоматического обновления данных при изменениях в БД) - данные компоненты решают множество проблем работы с данными, как сохранение состояния при поворотах, получение уведомлений при изменении и пр.

Для первоначального ознакомления с возможностями и работой компонентов *Architecture Components* рекомендую почитать [эту серию уроков](http://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html) на русском языке. Здесь раскрыты все основные моменты, а так же основы работы с ORM Room

Так как работа с реляционной БД имеет множество нюансов и специальных знаний для правильной организации ее структуры и составления запросов, то рекомендую почитать отличную книгу по этой теме: *Бейли Л. - Изучаем SQL (Бестселлеры O'Reilly) - 2012 г.* - с ней вы наиболее легко и доступно ознакомитесь с этой сложной темой.

PS: другой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), связанный с темой хранения данных

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Не совсем это магазин, так для простоты понятия вопроса привела пример, думала сделать его локальным с сохранением данных на телефоне (а-ля подсчет потраченных денег и т.п.), поэтому БД с осторожностью пыталась обходить, конечно по плану дальше изучения ее, но пока для меня это как для мартышки арифметика...конечно с перспективой.

Comment: @ЕвгенияБалабанова Не стоит оттягивать неизбежное :) Наоборот отличный повод получить практику на реальной задаче. С книгой в ответе освоить работу с реляционной БД будет не сложно, написано очень доступно, впрочем как и все от издательства O`Reilly. Для задачи подсчета потраченных денег никаких вариантов, кроме использования БД нет в принципе, если вы хотите делать "по взрослому". Не забывайте, что здесь вам всегда помогут решить проблему, если вдруг сами вы не справитесь

Comment: это боль) не так все просто, буду разбираться, пока костыли сделала.... каждый пункт записала в примитивные данные и передаю их, а не объект, ну да ладно... СПАСИБО за СОВЕТЫ буду реализовывать потихоньку