# Как хранить данные?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста как хранить данные следующей задачи:
У меня есть плейлист треков с перечислением мета-данных (заголовок, артист, альбом...), мне необходимо получать доступ к этим данным, актуальным состоянием, из разных классов, фрагментов и т.д. Как такое делают правильно?

Comment: вам нужно как-то детальней описать проблему. Сейчас ответ база данных.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808842/177345