# Как получить id (или другой элемент) позиции, выбранной в spinner?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-spinner

Всем привет. 
Есть база Sqlite, элементы из этой базы (имя пользователя) можно выбрать в Spinner. Однако у меня не получается выбирать пароль в Textview при выборе пользователя.

То есть, например, есть две строки:

Пользователь Андрей, пароль 123,

Пользователь Борис, пароль 321.

Нужно, чтобы когда в Spinner выбрано "Андрей", в поле Textview было "123", а когда в Spinner выбрано "Борис", в поле Textview было "321".
Понимаю, что вопрос нуба, но решить не получается)

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner allusers;
    List<String> users=new ArrayList<>();
    EditText uname,upassword;
    Button adduser;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    DbHandler db;
    TextView myTextView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        allusers=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selectuser);
        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        upassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        adduser=(Button)findViewById(R.id.adduser);
        db=new DbHandler(MainActivity.this);
        adduser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username=uname.getText().toString();
                String password=upassword.getText().toString();
                if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("")||password.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter Username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    db.addUser(new User(username,password));
                    prepareData();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User was Successfully added to Database",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mPassword);
        prepareData();
        allusers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {             
            //AA
            User selected = (User) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            myTextView.setText(selected.getPassword());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}

public void prepareData() {
    users = db.getAllUsers();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, android.R.id.text1, users);
    allusers.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {
int id;
String name;
String password;
public User(String name, String password)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.password=password;
}
public User(int id, String name, String psd)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.password=psd;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**DbHandler.java**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private  static final int Db_Version=1;
    private static final String Db_Name="users";
    private static final String Table_Name="user";
    private static final String User_id="id";
    private static final String User_name="name";
    private static final String User_password="password";
    public DbHandler(Context context)
    {
        super(context,Db_Name,null,Db_Version);
    }
        @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String Create_Table="CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + "(" + User_id
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + User_name + " TEXT," + User_password + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(Create_Table);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
            onCreate(db);
    }
    public void addUser(User usr)
    {
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(User_name,usr.getName());
            cv.put(User_password,usr.getPassword());
            db.insert(Table_Name, null, cv);
            db.close();
    }
    public int checkUser(User us)
    {
        int id=-1;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM user WHERE name=? AND password=?",new String[]{us.getName(),us.getPassword()});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            id=cursor.getInt(0);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return id;
    }

    public List<String> getAllUsers()
    {
        List<String> userlist=new ArrayList<>();
           SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM user",null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
        do {
            userlist.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return userlist;
    }
}
```

Выделил комментарием "АА" код, который не отрабатывает. 
Прошу подсказать где ошибка.
Спасибо.

Comment: `users.get(parent.getSelectedItemPosition()).getPassword()`

Comment: Не получилось таким образом, в users нет .getPassword(), не компилируется.

Comment: String selected = users.get(parent.getSelectedItemPosition());
                myTextView.setText(selected);                        так выводит то, что в Spinner

Comment: точно) вообще странный код, вы пытаетесь `String` позицию привести к типу `User`. По-хорошему надо делать все иначе, например через `ArrayList<User> users`)) но для вашего кода могу предложить делать запрос в БД и искать по имени пароль. Костыль, но это проблема организации кода.

Comment: Задвоилась запись, исправил. Когда я вывожу  (long id): String selected = String.valueOf(id);
                myTextView.setText(selected);   первая запись выводится - 0. Я так понимаю, что это порядковый номер в массиве, а не в базе данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решилась добавлением запросов в DbHandler.

**UPD:**

В классе MainActivity в методе onItemSelected вместо

```
User selected = (User) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        myTextView.setText(selected.getPassword());
```

записать:

```
String my_id = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            int myId = db.getID(my_id);
            String selected = String.valueOf(myId);
            myTextView.setText(selected);
```

И в классе DbHandler добавить запрос:

```
public int getID(String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM user WHERE name ='" + name + "'", null);
    if(cursor!=null)
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    int s = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(User_id));
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return s;
}
```

Для вывода пароля тоже добавить аналогичный запрос, например getPassword

Answer (score 1):

При получении данных из курсора в список моделей вы сохраняете никакие не модели User, а первый столбец курсора в виде строки String (видимо это должен быть ID записи - число), этот же массив стрингов передаете в адаптер, но обратиться пытаетесь к методам модели User (получить из адаптера модели User, когда передали туда строки String)

Четвертый аргумент метода-колбэка `onItemSelected()` (long id) класса `OnItemSelectedListener` это и есть ID записи в БД, которую выбрали, но значение зависит от используемого адаптера, корректный ID этим аргументом возвращают только адаптеры, предназначенные непосредственно для работы с БД (как `SimpleCursorAdapter`). `ArrayAdapter`  возвращает этим аргументом позицию, так как о работе с БД ничего не знает.

Вы можете либо использовать подходящий адаптер (тогда вам надо работать напрямую с `Cursor`, а не моделью), либо сделать свой адаптер на основе используемого вами, переопределив в нем метод  `getItemId(position)`, чтобы он возвращал корректное значение ID , также сделать, чтобы он работал с моделью данных, а не одним типом.

Однако я бы рекомендовал вам не изобретать свой велосипед с извлечением из курсора в модели (почему [это не хорошо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809767/177345)), а воспользоваться комплексом решений Google [Architecture Componenets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808842/177345) в связке с ORM Room и support.v4.ListAdapter

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ. Задачу решил добавлением запроса в класс DbHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через debug посмотреть что у вас лежит в parent и как он присваивает значение. Если он не пуст, смотреть дальше, как отрабатывают все остальные методы, достающие password. Ну и на крайняк

```
myTextView.setText(selected.getPassword().toString());
```