# Одна БД, несколько активити. Соединение каждый раз. Это нормально?

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Всем здравия!

Вот недавно (совсем недавно) начал осваивать разработку приложений под андроид.

Вводная: 
Есть Андроид студио. 
Есть одна БД с шестью таблицами на sqlite. 
Есть четыре активити, которые отображают данные из этой БД. Отбор данных для каждой активити производится запросом из БД на основе переданного из предыдущего активити данных.

Моя реализация: 
при запуске каждого активити соединяюсь к БД по новой и запросом вытаскиваю нужные данные. Запихиваю все в массив, который привязан к RecycledView. 
Все работает и вроде даже довольно неплохо =)

Сомнения: 
Меня смущает часть соединения с БД в каждом активити. Мне это кажется каким-то ненормальным. Гугл подходящего ответа и/или другой реализации не подсказал. Хочется сделать одно соединение и дальше юзать его, потом в конце закрыть и все. А то при каждом переходе создается новое, не фэншуй однако. Есть опасения что это при более масштабных проектах может оказаться узким местом.

Вопрос:
Как работать с базой в рамках одной "сессии" с одним подключением?

З.Ы. Возможны каламбуры с терминологией, прошу простить. Я в семье Андроидовых новенький =)

Comment: вас должео смущать совсем другое - перегонка данных из базы в массив [несоизмеримо большие затраты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), чем открытие подключения при каждом обращении, так делают только в упрощенных учебных примерах. по соединению - можно открывать один раз где нибудь в наследнике Application и [не закрывать потом даже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345), но и ваш вариант нормальный

Comment: Благодарю за предметную критику, будем учиться дальше! как раз все по учебным примерам и делал =))

Comment: Прочитал по первой ссылке. В оправдание могу сказать что в массивы перекачиваю не всю таблицу(ы), а только отобранные и нужные мне данные - в результате запроса получаю от 5 до 10 элементов, редко больше 10.

Comment: ваше решение, помимо затрат ресурсов на копирование имеет множество других существенных недостатков, как необходимость обрабатывать два источника данных - ваш массив и данные в БД, синхронизировать их (изменяя, добавляя или удаляя значения в массиве нужно делать то же самое и в БД и наоборот - двойная работа и крайне плрхая архитектура). массив - динамические данные, они существуют, пока существует объект, в котором он создан, при, например, повороте устройства этот массив будет потерян или нужно предпринимать дополнительные действия для его сохранения - все это лишнее.. много и других проблем

Comment: =) Жесть! Я вас понял. Иду учиться. Молчу

Comment: вообще сейчас есть хорошая архитектура работы с данными от гугл - [android arhitecture components](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808842/177345) (вторая часть ответа). рекомендую сразу работать с ней, данная архитектура решает множество проблем. так же sqlite требует отдельных специфических знаний по работе с реляционными БД - это на самом деле сложно и объемно, если использовать связи, сложные запросы и тд