# Как сохранить динамически формирующийся ArrayList<Object> и восстановить его после перезапуска приложения?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Есть ArrayList с кастомным классом:

```
static ArrayList<ItemClass> favoritItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Для него есть адаптер:

```
ItemClass adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, favoritItems);
```

В ArrayList добавляются данные динамически, т.е. в ходе работы пользователя в приложении. Далее, данные из массива отображаются в отдельном активити в кач-ве списка.

ItemClass:

```
public class ItemClass implements Comparable<ItemClass> {

    private String mNomenclatreBarCode;
    private String mNomenclatureName;
    private String mNomenclatureWeight;
    private String mNomenclatureComposition;
    private String mNomenclatureBrand;
    private String mNomenclaturePercent;
    private int mImageResourse;
    private String mNomenclaturePack;
    private String mNomenclatureDate;

    public ItemClass(String NomenclatureBarCode, String NomenclatureName, String NomenclatureWeight,
                     String NomenclatureBrand, String NomenclaturePercent,
                     String NomenclatureComposition, int ImageResourse, String NomenclaturePack, String NomenclatureDate) {
        mNomenclatreBarCode = NomenclatureBarCode;
        mNomenclatureName = NomenclatureName;
        mNomenclatureWeight = NomenclatureWeight;
        mNomenclatureComposition = NomenclatureComposition;
        mNomenclatureBrand = NomenclatureBrand;
        mNomenclaturePercent = NomenclaturePercent;
        mImageResourse = ImageResourse;
        mNomenclaturePack = NomenclaturePack;
        mNomenclatureDate = NomenclatureDate;
    }

    public String getNomenclatureBarCode() {
        return mNomenclatreBarCode;
    }

    public String getNomenclatureName() {
        return mNomenclatureName;
    }

    public String getNomenclatureWeight() {
        return mNomenclatureWeight;
    }

    public String getNomenclatureComposition() {
        return mNomenclatureComposition;
    }

    public String getNomeclatureBrand() {
        return mNomenclatureBrand;
    }

    public String getNomenclaturePercent() {
        return mNomenclaturePercent;
    }

    public int getImageResourse() {
        return mImageResourse;
    }

    public String getNomenclaturePack() {
        return mNomenclaturePack;
    }

    public String getNomenclatureDate() {
        return mNomenclatureDate;
    }

    public int compareTo(ItemClass other) {
        return mNomenclatureName.compareTo(other.mNomenclatureName);
    }
}
```

Как сохранить эти данные после перезапуска приложения? Чтобы при открытии страницы с данными этого массива они оставались на своем месте.

Comment: Скиньте что там внутри класса `ItemClass`

Comment: @Flippy обновил в вопросе.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоритически можно сделать класс ItemClass сериализуемым и сохранять значения в файл

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myFile.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(obj); // obj - ваш объект
oos.close();
```

а при страрте читать

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myFile.ser");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Object obj = ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

По хорошему надо в БД сохранять.

Answer (score 1):

Впринципе для таких вещей есть выбор, но я считаю, что самый правильный - это база данных. Советую [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow). Подключить буквально пару секунд, пометить ваш класс аннотацией `@Table`, создать класс и пометить его `@Database`. Все поля класса пометить `@Column`. Далее при добавлении в список вызывать у объекта метод `save()` который сохранит его в БД. А при запуске приложения получать данные из БД.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я совсем недавно в java. Буду разбираться.