# Как передать значение переменной в другую активность?

Tags: java, android

есть активность в виде корзины покупок ,в ней передаётся название ,цена и количество.
Вот так:

```
public void getDataFromDatabase(){

    data = dbhelper.getAllData();

    double Order_price = 0;
    double Total_price = 0;
    double tax = 0;

    // хранить все данные в переменных
    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(i);

        String Menu_name = row.get(1).toString();
        String Quantity = row.get(2).toString();
        double Sub_total_price = Double.parseDouble(formatData.format(Double.parseDouble(row.get(3).toString())));
        Order_price += Sub_total_price;

        // рассчитать цену заказа
        OrderList += ("\n"+"Количество:"+Quantity+"\n"+"Название:"+Menu_name+"\n"+"Сумма:"+Sub_total_price+" "+Currency);
    }
```

Затем эти данные отправляются по смс
Вот так:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                smsIntent.putExtra("address" , new String (Menu_serve));

                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Заказчик: "+Name+"\n"+"Адрес:"+Alamat+""+OrderList+"\n"+"Коментарий:"+Comment);
                startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Так же имеется ещё одна активность `ActivityDetal`,в ней отображается картинка ,цена и тексты.
В виде:

```
txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
 txtSubText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
```

и

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // if internet connection and data available show data
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if((Menu_name != null) && IOConnect == 0){
            sclDetail.setVisibility(0);

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+Menu_image, imgPreview);

            txtText.setText(Menu_name);
            txtSubText.setText("Цена: " +Menu_price+" "+ActivityMenuList.Currency+"\n"+"Статус: "+Menu_serve);
            txtDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Menu_description, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
            txtDescription.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }
```

Как я могу из активности ActivityDetal передать Menu_serve в активность корзины покупок? А именно для того что можно было вставить номер из значения 
 `Menu_serve` в
`smsIntent.putExtra("address" , new String (Menu_serve));`
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что представляет собой Menu_serve?

Comment: вы используете базу данных. вам не нужно что то передавать между активностями, вам нужно читать из БД в той активности, где требуются данные, составив соответствующий запрос на выбрку нужных, а не собирать в какие то массивы и таскать их потом туда сюда. смотрите так же [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345).