# Как присвоить номер телефона к OrderList для корзины покупок

Tags: java, android, sql

Есть программа с корзиной покупок,где имеется кнопка добавления товара в корзину с помощью `DBHelper` создаётся `OrderList` из которого формируется форма для отправки по смс .
При нажатии на кнопку:

```
// когда нажали кнопку добавления, добавить меню в таблицу заказов в базе данных
        if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
                    dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                }else{
                    dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                }
        }else{
            dialog.cancel();
        }                   
      }
    });
```

и есть ещё одна строка `Menu_quantity` где имеется номер телефона который я хочу присвоить для `OrderList`.

```
txtText.setText(Menu_name);
            txtSubText.setText("Цена: " +Menu_price+" "+ActivityMenuList2.Currency+"\n"+"Статус: "+Menu_serve+"\n"+"В наличии: "+Menu_quantity);
            txtDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Menu_description, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

**Проблема в том что при добавлении `Menu_quantity` в `dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));` или создания нового `dbhelper.addData` получаю номер телефона в каждом товаре из списка, а я пытаюсь сделать чтобы номер присвоился как единый для всего списка.**
[image: Вот скрин создания списка заказов.]

[image: А это скрин отправки заказа]

Comment: видимо вам нужно организовать связь "один ко многим" , каждому элементу одного заказа присвоить id этой группы (заказа) и в отдельной таблице хранить телефон к такой группе по ее id

Comment: @pavlofff Я думаю это слишком сложновато. Мне надо как нибудь передать переменную или присвоить переменную `Menu_quantity` к `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data;` но так что бы можно было её опубликовать в Phone.equalsIgnoreCase("")){Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                    smsIntent.putExtra("address" , new String(Phone));smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",Name+"\n"+"Адрес:"+Alamat+""+OrderList);
                    startActivity(smsIntent);`

Comment: это правильное решение по дисциплине СУБД, а какие костыли вы себе придумаете от недостатка знаний по предмету и как все это будет потом  работать  - это уже ваша фантазия и ваши же проблемы. (немного резко получилось, но ничего такого не хотел, хотел сказать что есть правильное решение, а есть нет)

Comment: и вот [еще одно замечание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) по [не]правильности архитектуры

Comment: @pavlofff Конечно не достаток знания имеется,так как я только начинаю изучение программирования.  Вы бы не могли предоставить пример реализации такой связи упомянутой вами в первом коменте?

Comment: Это в общем то стандартный шаблон СУБД - one to many (один ко многим) и описан во множестве литературы. По СУБД могу посоветовать почитать книгу Линн Бейли "Изучаем SQL" , там очень доступно и с примерами написаны все основы проектирования и работы с реляционными базами данных