# Android. Где хранить изменяемые строковые ресурсы?

Tags: java, android

Есть готовое приложение учета зарплаты. В нем есть 5 категорий - зарплата, аванс, больничные, отпускные, иное. Категории хранятся в базе SQLite значениями 0-4 соответственно. Сейчас конвертация названия категории происходит в методе, который присваивает название по номеру из базы. Также, при добавлении в базу есть выпадающий список с этими категориями, которые хранятся в виде строкового массива в файле ресурсов.
Хочу реализовать возможность переименования этих категорий пользователем. Можно добавить еще одну колонку в таблицу БД со строковым наименованием категории, но менять существующую структуру не хочется. Где и как еще это можно делать?

Comment: нужно было сразу хранить всю динамическую информацию в БД. никакого другого разумного способа, не предполагающего диких костылей, нет и если вы хотите сделать правильно, то придется все же захотеть переделать структуру. Видимо так же нужно пересмотреть вообще весь подход к данным в приложении, так как озвученное вами решение наводит на мысль, что подобная вещь у вас не единственная. так же хорошо бы [прочитать эту информацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), почему то я уверен, что для вас она актуальна.