# Android Studio не реагирует на исправление синтаксической ошибки SQLite-запроса

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, syntax

Описывая создание таблицы в строке запроса я забыл поставить пробел между EXISTS и именем таблицы.
Ошибку исправил - вставил пробел. Однако android studio продолжает выдавать ту же самую ошибку, указывая старую строку, где пробела нет.
 Пытался исправить и другими способами: удалял приложение из эмулятора, делал
sync gradle, rebuild procject, clean project, invalidate cache/restart, даже перезапускал компьютер. Ошибка остается прежней.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{e.mi.work3/e.mi.work3.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTSstudent": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSstudent (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fio TEXT, time TEXT)`

**Класс, описывающий таблицу** и содержащий ту самую строку для запроса `SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES`

```
 package e.mi.work3.Data;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class Student {

private int ID;
private String FIO;
private String time;

public static class StudentEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "student";
    public final static String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public final static String COLUMN_FIO = "fio";
    public final static String COLUMN_TIME = "time";

    public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            StudentEntry.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            StudentEntry.COLUMN_FIO + " TEXT, " +
            StudentEntry.COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT)";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME;

        public static String getSqlCreateEntries() {
            return SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES;
        }

    public static String getSqlDeleteEntries() {
        return SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES;
    }
}



public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getFIO() {
    return FIO;
}

public void setFIO(String FIO) {
    this.FIO = FIO;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

}

**Класс, создающий таблицу.**

```
package e.mi.work3.database;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import e.mi.work3.Data.Student;


public class StudentsDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Students.db";

public StudentsDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Student.StudentEntry.getSqlCreateEntries());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(Student.StudentEntry.getSqlDeleteEntries());
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

public long insertStudent(String ID, String FIO, String time) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_ID,ID);
    values.put(Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_FIO,FIO);
    values.put(Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_TIME,time);

    long rawId = db.insert(Student.StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    return rawId;
}

public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudent() {
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query =
            "SELECT * FROM " + Student.StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME +
            " ORDER BY " + Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_TIME;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_ID)));
            student.setFIO(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_FIO)));
            student.setTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.StudentEntry.COLUMN_TIME)));

            studentList.add(student);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return studentList;
}

public void deleteAllStudents(){
    int rowsNumberDeleted;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    rowsNumberDeleted = db.delete(Student.StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    Log.i("info",String.valueOf(rowsNumberDeleted) + " students is deleted from database while launching");
}
```

}

---

**UPD**
Я целый день сидел над этой ошибкой. Только сейчас заметил странную связь:  в  MainACtivity я получаю массив объектов, которые наполняю данными через getAllStudents в классе StudentsDbHelper. В MainActivity я могу вывести данные этого объекта в лог. Значит тут все в порядке.
Однако мне нужно получить массив этих объектов в другом активити. Для этого в mainActivity у меня есть статический метод getStudentListInstance().
Воторое активити - это recyclerView. Когда адаптер во втором активити принимает ранее созданный в MainActivity список объектов через MainActivity.getStudentListInstance(), все идет хорошо. Однако если раскоментировать строку, в которой я УСТАНАВЛИВАЮ адаптер для recyclerView, то парадоксально *нелогично* возникает описанная *выше* ошибка.

**класс MainActivity**

```
package e.mi.work3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import e.mi.work3.Data.Student;
import e.mi.work3.Data.Util;
import e.mi.work3.database.StudentsDbHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<Student> studentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StudentsDbHelper dbHelper = new StudentsDbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.deleteAllStudents();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        dbHelper.insertStudent(String.valueOf(i + 1),
                Util.getStudentRandomRaw(),
                Util.getCurrentTime());
    }

    studentList = dbHelper.getAllStudent();
    Log.i("info",studentList.get(0).getFIO());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseInfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public static ArrayList<Student> getStudentListInstance() {
    return studentList;
}
```

}

**Класс второго активити**

```
package e.mi.work3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import e.mi.work3.Data.Student;
import e.mi.work3.database.StudentsDbHelper;

public class DatabaseInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview_student);


    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.getStudentListInstance(),this);

    RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewStudent);

    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

//        rv.setAdapter(adapter);  //**Здесь и возникает ошибка.**
}
```

}

**Код адаптера** (в ответ на комментарий под вопросом)`
    package e.mi.work3;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import e.mi.work3.Data.Student;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Student> data;
Context m;

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_student
            ,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.id.setText(data.get(i).getID());
    myViewHolder.fio.setText(data.get(i).getFIO());
    myViewHolder.time.setText(data.get(i).getTime());

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView id;
    TextView fio;
    TextView time;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        id = v.findViewById(R.id.idStudent);
        fio = v.findViewById(R.id.fioStudent);
        time = v.findViewById(R.id.timeStudentAdded);
    }
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Student> data, Context m) {
    this.data = data;
    this.m = m;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

}`

Comment: MainActivity.getStudentListInstance() - нельзя так данные между активити передавать, если конечно вы специально не рассчитываете, что ваша программа должна падать в непредсказуемые моменты, развлекая этим несчастных пользователей

Comment: А как передавать массив объектов (объектов, потому что они содержат в себе сразу несколько типов данных, которые удобно получать из объектов) не прибегая к Parceable?

Comment: в вашем случае данные нужно получать там, где они требуются, то есть во второй активити. если они зависят от значений первой, то нужно передавать эти значения простыми типами через интент и делать по ним запрос во второй. так же нужно [понять эту информацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345)

Comment: Возможно у вас в адаптере какой-то старый дубрированный код. Покажите адаптер.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил код в пост