# Как преобразовать Cursor в нужный класс?

Tags: java, android

Есть таблица SQLite и

```
ExampleClass exClass = new ExampleClass;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(request, null);
```

Как заполнить exClass данными из cursor быстрым способом, т.е. не по одному (cursor.getInt(....))?

Comment: Может быть попробовать Заюзать Room

Comment: Если у вас Cursor, правильно [работать и дальше с ним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), а не гонять данные по массивам. Если нужны модели данных, то использовать ORM, NoSQL. Никакого "быстрого" способа решения вашей проблемы не существует, только последовательный перебор каждого значения.