# Android, ListView. Сохранить данные так, чтобы, закрывая приложение, добавленные элементы массива сохранялись

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-shared-preferences

Есть String массив, который лежит в основе ListView, с помощью Button добавляется новый элемент массива. При выходе из приложения все добавленные элементы теряются. Как сделать так, чтобы они сохранялись и были доступны при новом входе в активити? На данном этапе пытаюсь использовать SharedPreferences, но все попытки мимо. Спасибо.

```
public class SubjectList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList subject = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String txt;
    EditText nameSubject;
    Button addSubject;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_list);

        subject.add("123");
        subject.add("1234");
        subject.add("12345");

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subject);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        nameSubject = findViewById(R.id.nameSubject);

        final SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("Subject", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("Subject", nameSubject.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();



        addSubject = findViewById(R.id.btnAddSubj);
        addSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt = nameSubject.getText().toString();
                subject.add(sp.getString("Subject", "DEFAULT"));
                nameSubject.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны сохранять свои данные независимо от ListView или любой другой сущности, отвечающей за UI. Все что должен знать ListView это то какие данные показать и как их показать.

Сохранение должно происходить независимо от ListView. Где? Это уже вопрос вашей архитектуры. Например вы можете сохранять их куда-то в кеш сразу после получения данных из сети. Или вы можете сохранять готовый список данных для отображения в сущности которая отвечает за логику работы вашего экрана (Presenter, ViewModel и т.д.)

Добавление новых элементов тоже должно изначально быть обработано где-то в другом месте, опять же Presenter, ViewModel и т.п. А в список должен всякий раз передаваться новый список.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сериализацией воспользоваться. Но не уверен, подойдёт ли это Вам в данном случае.

Comment: Решил проблему с помощью SharedPreferences, если интересно почитать как, могу прикрепить код)