# Почему при перевороте экрана ArrayList очищается

Tags: java, android

У меня имеется ListView и мой кастомный адаптер и при смене ориентации экрана элементы моего списка пропадают. Я попробовал сделать в другой активности такую же операцию с обычным адаптером и получилось, что элементы оставались, но добавлялись новые, то есть java код снова как бы подгружался и добавлял в имеющийся массив элементы.

Я проверил код оригинального адптера и ничего отвечающего за это не нашел, но придумал свое решение это при смене ориентации выполнять заполнение снова. Основной вопрос, это как отслеживать состояние экрана ориентации экрана и есть ли другое решение?

Comment: Используйте мотоды onRestoreInstanceState() и onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: @Circassian, сейчас попробую, но уверен, что получится

Comment: Если у вас фрагмент, установите флаг setRetainInstance(true) и фрагмент не будет уничтожаться при повороте

Comment: Так же в тему почитать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю вам стоит почитать про [жизненный цикл активити](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=ru), раз вы задаете такие вопросы.

Что происходит когда вы поворачиваете экран? Происходит смена конфигурации, а это значит, что активити пересоздается, а это означает, что все переменные которые были в ней инициализируются заново.

Если вам нужно сохранить состояние экрана - то вам надо обрабатывать это ручками. Тут несколько основных пунктов:

- Элементы которые в вашей XML разметке имеют уникальный id автоматически сохранят состояние. Это все происходит под капотом. Но только если вы назначили им id.
- Если же вам надо какие-то простые данные, то для этого есть методы `onSaveInstanceState()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Первый сохраняет ваши данные в Bundle, второй позволяет вам извлечь их. Этот способ подходит для простых переменных (например сохранит флаг, id или текст какой-то) т.к. размер бандла ограничен.
- Если же вам нужно хранить какие-то объемные данные, то вам нужно их сохранять где-то в другом месте. Например в базу данных или же любую другую сущность которая живет независимо от вашей активити, а после каждой смены конфигурации снова получать эти самые данные.